# how to quote parameters in source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have two (org-mode) source blocks, both with parameters:

```
select-union(tbl=a_table)
```

and

```
column-names(tbl=a_table)
```

Both produce SQL artifacts from the table data.
Now I want to write a new source block which calls both of these.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql :var tab=an_example_table 
;with src as (
  select * from (
    <<select-union(tbl=tab)>>
  ) X(<<column-names(tbl=tab)>>)
)
select * from src
#+END_SRC
```

This errors at me in a somewhat unfriendly manner, something about tab not being a valid block name. So here's my question:

In a source block A, how do I call another source block B with one of A's parameters as parameter value?

Comment: Try updating your `:var` header to  `:var tab="an_example_table"`. Did that resolve the problem?

Comment: Also I'm guessing you set `:noweb yes` header somewhere else in the file?

Comment: Yep, :noweb yes is set. I tried your solution and got an "org-babel-ref-resolve: Reference 'tab' not found in this buffer" message. Seems that variable names are not resolved in block arguments.

Comment: I haven't done a SQL code block yet. Perhaps there is a special syntax for SQL?  Have you tried `tbl=$tab` ? I found this works for dot code blocks.

Comment: Yes, I've tried. After some reading in the org code, it looks like names in noweb references are resolved before variable replacement. If I'm not very much mistaken, what I want cannot be done.

Comment: I wonder if this issue is specific to SQL blocks because I've passed variables to noweb blocks. This issue reminds of special case where I had to pass the variable value in 2 steps. Unfortunately I'm replying from my phone so I'm going off of my memory instead of having answer in front of me. Try something like this: `<<select-union[ :var myvar=tab](tbl=myvar)>>`. Here's an example in Ruby, `<<my_ruby_code_block[ :var d='(1 2)](data=#{d})>>`

Comment: Tried it, does not work either. Sadface

Comment: Bummer!! Sadface!! I forgot to ask what version of emacs and org-mode you're using. I just reproduced your issue using `sh` code block instead of `sql`. I also found a work around which we haven't covered yet. But I'm not sure if it will work for you. Just for syntax checking, if you used `;with src as ( $tab )` does your select return same results as `select * from an_example_table`?